# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo and calling of another activity in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, nullpointerexception, crash

I'm new to android development and trying to create a simple register application but the application crash every time I click the Register Here TextView. Other than that, I code the login button to try the calling of another activity but it has no respond after I click the button. I tried so hard to find the mistakes but I'm not sure that what I missed in the coding.

This is the main activity

```
package com.fyp4201.universityguide;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TabHost;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TabHost tabHost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabHost host = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    host.setup();

    //Tab 1
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("tab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Home");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 2
    spec = host.newTabSpec("tab2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Search Courses");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 3
    spec = host.newTabSpec("tab3");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec.setIndicator("Search University");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab4
    spec = host.newTabSpec("tab4");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab4);
    spec.setIndicator("Compare Universities");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab5
    spec = host.newTabSpec("tab5");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab5);
    spec.setIndicator("Ranking of Universities");
    host.addTab(spec);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
   switch( item.getItemId()){

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
       case R.id.action_settings: {
        return true;
    }
       case R.id.action_login:{
       Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
   }
       default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}}
```

This is codes for login activity

```
package com.fyp4201.universityguide;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TextView regis = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register);
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Homeafterlogin.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
});


regis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Register.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
});

}}
```

This is codes for Register activity

```
package com.fyp4201.universityguide;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://jrfyp4201.site88.net/volleyRegister.php";
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_CONTACTNO = "contactno";

private EditText etname,etuname,etpass,etconpass,etemail,etcontactno;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

     etname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
     etuname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uname);
     etpass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
     etconpass= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conpass);
     etemail= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    etcontactno= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contactno);
}

public void onRegisterbtnClick(View view ){
   registerUser();
}


public void registerUser(){
    final String username = etuname.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = etpass.getText().toString().trim();
    final String name = etname.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = etemail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String contactno = etcontactno.toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            params.put(KEY_NAME, name);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            params.put(KEY_CONTACTNO, contactno);

            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

This is the logcat error file

```
   Process: com.fyp4201.universityguide, PID: 20646
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fyp4201.universityguide/com.fyp4201.universityguide.Register}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2264)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:711)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at com.fyp4201.universityguide.Register.onCreate(Register.java:20)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5340)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2228)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2313) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:141) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:711) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

XML files of register activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.fyp4201.universityguide.Register"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_register">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name :"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editname"
         />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username :"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edituname"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password :"
        android:id="@+id/textView4" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editpass"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Confirm Password :"
        android:id="@+id/textView7" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editconpass"
       />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E-mail address :"
        android:id="@+id/textView5" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editemail"
       />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contact Number :"
        android:id="@+id/textView6" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editcontactno"
       />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Register"
        android:id="@+id/registerbtn"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="onRegisterbtnClick" />
</LinearLayout>
```

XML file of login activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.fyp4201.universityguide.LoginActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_login2">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Username"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/loginuname" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Password"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/loginpass" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:onClick="onLoginClick" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Register Here!"
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/accent_material_light"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onRegisterClick" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please tell me what I missed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check all the ids in the xml files and correct their name in java.
It seems like you are referencing an id of another xml file thats not associated with this activity like you might be refering a username field of login xml file in registration activity and vice versa

Comment: Thanks for replying my question. I checked the ids of xml files but nothing wrong there in my opinion. All the ids are unique and refer to the correct activity or maybe i missed something. Should I upload the xml files here?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, i fixed the problem. There's no problem with the codings just the application is not updated after changes had been made. It is fixed after i clean and rebuild the project. Thank you .